# Android Map V2 changes UI

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]

Hello,
can anybody give me solution for how to change place of current location default icon (as rounded in above image right corner) from right corner to left corner.?
thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I just enabled location button.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4670), you can reposition the items by using `GoogleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)`.

Here is the actual statement:

> We added GoogleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom), which allows you to indicate parts of the map that may be obscured by other views. Setting padding re-positions the standard map controls, and camera updates will use the padded region.
>
> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_padding

Comment: This is not a solution that will help placing my location button on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you should hide the default my location button and add your own `Button` to the layout on the left side, handling `onClick` to call `animateCamera`. You cannot reuse default button's drawables this way.

Note: this is not a good idea, because other apps will have this button in the right corner in other apps using maps and may expect it to be there in your app.